# Visual Basic Program will not launch on other PC's

Tags: vb.net

I first off build my finished program from Visual Basic, so I go to my bin folder to give the 'Megtool.exe' to my mate.

But he can't open it on his pc? It just doesn't do anything, no errors or anything. I disabled "enable application framework", and if you could help I don't also want them to get anything. If any ideas of how to fix, please comment thanks :D

Comment: Does he have .net framework installed on his PC?

Comment: Is there any recorded error into [Event Viewer](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/what-information-event-logs-event-viewer#1TC=windows-7)?

Comment: are you using any 3rd party component? Have a look at your bin folder, most of the files in there need to be copied to the user's PC